# The image of the interval $(a , b)$ under a lipschitz continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a lipschitz continuous function. Let $(a , b)$ be an open interval. Is it true that $f((a , b)) = (f(a) , f(b))$?

Comment: $\sin((0, 2\pi))$?

Comment: @user251257 Yes you are right! So what is the necessary condition for this to hold? Is it that $f$ is increasing continuous?

Comment: increasing continuous is sufficient. necessary $f(a)$ is the infimum, and $f(b)$ is the supremum. $f$ needs not even be continuous.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you so much.